# PyRun_InteractiveLoop globals/locals

Tags: python

I am trying to set local/globals variables in PyRun_InteractiveLoop call.
Cant figure out how to do it, since, unlike exec counterparts, loop doesn't accept global/local args.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need globals and locals for this? You don't need a "subcontext"; just set up the main context, the same way you would before `PyRun_AnyFile`.

Comment: Also, the code to these high-level convenience methods isn't exactly hidden, or hard to understand. Take a look at the [2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c) or [3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Python/pythonrun.c) implementation, and if you can't figure out how to do what you want with `PyAST_Compile` plus `Py_EvalCode`, ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a C API version of exec, maybe try `PyRun_File` and its ilk?  Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish though.

Comment: I want interactive prompt/IDLE/shell

Comment: Those are three different things.